# How to debug the "message" function on entry ?

Tags: debugging, message

While debugging a minor mode (separate issue), I wanted to generate a stack trace of the message function so I thought I would just enter

```
M-x debug-on-entry RET message
```

I was quite surprised to see that this method did not work. No stack trace was generated instead I started to get the error

```
Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'
```

Which probably means that the message function was being called from the debugger, and debugger was calling message again making an infinite loop. Is there a more fool-proof way of generating full traces of who called the message function ?

Comment: While I agree with @phils, this error you got was actually a bug, which I just fixed in Emacs's master branch.

Comment: Was it this ? http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=872481d9e26d7569145c897fd319b1104e028878.

Comment: Yes, tho only the `debug.el` part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the `debug-on-message` variable in this situation.

```
If non-nil, debug if a message matching this regexp is displayed.
```

Comment: Good answer, was it easy to find in the docs ? I tried apropos but gave up maybe too quickly.

Comment: It's certainly easy if you already know it's there :) I first spotted it in the NEWS file when 24.3 was released. Searching for "debug" with `apropos` finds it quickly enough, I think? In the manual you can find it under both `(elisp) Error Debugging` and also `(elisp) Explicit Debug`, and a repeated isearch for "message" in the debugger section turns it up pretty soon. So yeah... you probably gave up a bit early in this instance.